# How to style JavaScript created text using CSS's @font-face

Tags: javascript, css, raphael, font-face

I'm trying to create a page which uses java script to get data via PHP and then display it using a custom font declared in a CSS style sheet.
The entire page should use one custom font which I have declared in the main CSS file using @font-face like so:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'bauhaus';
    src: url('fonts/Bauhaus.woff') format('woff'),
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal; }
```

My HTML file looks like this:

```
<html>  
<head> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/raphael-min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/index.js"></script> 
    <link href="Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css">  
        #canvas_container {  
            width: 100%;  
            border: 1px solid #aaa; 
            font-family:'bauhaus', "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        }  
    </style>  
</head>  
<body>  
    <div id="canvas_container">FONTTEST</div>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Within the `index.js` I can create text objects using Raphaeljs' syntax like so:

```
var txt = paper.text(150, 590, 'Test123').attr({'font-family': bauhaus, 'font-size':'70', fill:'#000'});
```

If I do it like that no 'Test123' text appears at all (I assume because it can't find or use the style 'bauhaus') and if I remove the font-family attribute it shows me text using the browser's default style which in my case is Arial.
The 'FONTTEST' text on the other hand is displayed correctly using the correct @font-face Font.

Now my question is how to automatically have text created by Raphaeljs (or other Javascript libraries) follow the style declared by the CSS statements? I like using custom fonts but I can't find a proper solution on how to easily use the stylized text with Javascript.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after a bit of searching through Raphael's code I found it automatically sets its own font style (Arial) on all its text elements. I don't think that really makes sense, especially since I couldn't figure out on how to override it with a CSS '@font-face' font, but ok.
My solution was to simply delete the automatic setting of the font attribute in Raphael's source code.

For anyone interested, it's in the part where `theText` is declared. Just delete the `font: availableAttrs.font` bit in `res.attrs`and everything will obey the CSS style you want.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than writing out your CSS attributes in-line in your JS, why not change your CSS at the top from #canvas_container to .canvas_container , and then put the attribute "class='canvas_container' " on all of your elements which you want that font on? Should be easier to specify the class attribute than the style attribute.

An even better approach, if you want the entire page to use your font, would be to put this in your CSS (in your case, the style element):

```
html, body { font-family: 'bauhaus', "Times New Roman", Times, serif; }
```

That will make all HTML and BODY elements use your font unless later overwritten.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately both don't work. If I set the font globally like you proposed, all text written in the html file will be the proper font, but any text created with RaphaelJS is still not styled properly. I've even tried to access the object via jquery and set the style `$(txt.node).addClass("canvas_container");` but that doesn't work either. I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the font with cufon. See http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.registerFont and https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/about.

Answer (score -1):

You can assign the style of your text explicitly not thinking about what really does.

Write a specific styler object function like:

```
function Styler( style )
{
  this._style = style;

  this.get = function( text)
  {
    return "<span style=" + this._style + "'>" + text + "</span>";
  }
}
```

and then use everywhere:

```
myStyler = new Styler( 'font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold' );

    ...

    text1 = myStyler.get( "text1" );
    text2 = myStyler.get( "text2" );
```